# ¿Como solucionar error de conexión de TZConnection para conectar con una base de datos?

Tags: pascal, lazarus

Tengo Lazarus 1.7 + Zeos + wampserver 3.1.7. Cuando intento conectar mi TZConnection con la base de datos en MySql, me sale este mensaje de error:

> no se puede encontrar ninguna de las bibliotecas dinámicas o no se puede cargar libmysql57.dll, libmysql 56.dll, libmysql 55.dll, libmysql 51.dll, libmysql 50.dll, libmariadb.dll, libmysql.dll
>
> Utilizar TZConnection.LibraryLocation si la ubicación es inválida

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? He buscado en muchas páginas pero aun no encuentro solución.

Comment: Dado que tienes instalado WampServer, supongo que alguna de esas bibliotecas (dll) que lista el mensaje de error existen en tu equipo. ¿Las has buscado? ¿dónde se encuentran ubicadas las que encuentras? ¿Qué versión de MySQL tienes instalada?

Comment: Las he intentado budcar pero no las encuentro en mi PC, no se bien en que carpeta encontrarlas, MySql con PhpMyAdmin 4.8.4

Comment: Sugiero que salgas a cmd y en la raíz de cada disco que tengas hagas `dir libmysql*.dll /s`. Con eso verás cuales tienes y en que carpetas.

Comment: Lo intente pero me manda un mensaje que no aparece el archivo o no se si hize algo mal